# How to know training status on aws sagemaker if I lost internet connection and returned on the kernel

Tags: amazon-web-services, lstm, amazon-sagemaker

I was training in aws Sagemaker Jupyter Lab( p3.2xlarge instance) and It was LSTM network and suddenly internet connection got lost and When I returned to the kernel when I got internet connection back..I could not see any training epochs updated.

Does anyone know that can I access what is processing in the kernel by terminal or something so I will know the training status.

Answer (score 4):

You can view the logs using CloudWatch. To get there go to SageMaker sidebar and drop down the Training section and select Training Jobs. There you should see a list of your training jobs. Click on the job that is in progress and scroll down to the Monitor section. There you should see an option to View Logs.

I know there's a good chance you figured this out by now but I answered just in case somebody runs into the same problem, just like I did.